# Looking for shapefiles of map of assembly constituencies of India?

Tags: india, geospatial

I used shapefile from the link: https://github.com/datameet/maps/tree/master/assembly-constituencies

to create district and assembly constituency level maps of India. While the district maps look fine. The assembly constituency level map has a huge chunk of Uttar Pradesh missing.

[image]

Comment: Welcome Farah. *How* did you produce the map? Are you asking if the data is complete? Are you asking why your software does not work? Also, your title is completely different from your text. **What is your actual question?** Please [edit] your question to make it clearer.

Comment: Standard question: have you looked at openstreetmap.org?